# HMAC calculation in SQL compared to C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, cryptography, hmac

I need to do a HMAC calculation in SQL (SQL Server 2012) that gives the same value as my calculation in C#, obviously.
The C# implementation works. It uses the standard .NET class [HMACSHA512](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha512(v=vs.110).aspx).

I would like to avoid using SQL CLR, and instead use [this SQL implementation](https://gist.github.com/rmalayter/3130462) that I belive should work according to other posts.

I'm having a feeling that the problem is the way I'm casting my varchars to varbinaries for the HMAC input parameters. I'm using it like this:

```
DECLARE @hash VARBINARY(64) = (
    SELECT dbo.HMAC('SHA2_512',         -- Hash alg.
        CAST('1234' AS VARBINARY),      -- Key
        CAST('12345678' AS VARBINARY))  -- Data
);

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), @hash, 2) hash_varchar

-- Output: 180F85FDA172A3F1CCEAA25D4D63A05C03F0BF8D664A7AD81E2FE1FB2FF3D4BA754B90A75C58B1D2B8A11C52192CAF307658B4B6A81D06ECB2667F37DA753619
```

Calculating the hash for the same key and data using the C# class, yields the following output:

```
8DB72756190593E0849AC6CA9B0DB4D3E0A1439AB2D9ECD6D07406020EEA6EE824A89C3DA0633B66AFE5BBA8D4CC5AB59347E8137F5AF6521725307B4DC8BCB5
```

For reference, here's my exact C# [implementation](https://gist.github.com/thj-dk/47778a7a56a4d98dbd58).

Am I doing something wrong, or is it the implementation of the HMAC function?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [RFC2202 Test Cases for HMAC-MD5 and HMAC-SHA-1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2202). Look at test case 1 for SHA1:

```
test_case =     1
key =           0x0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b
key_len =       20
data =          "Hi There"
data_len =      8
digest =        0xb617318655057264e28bc0b6fb378c8ef146be00
```

The C# implementation returns the correct value. The T-SQL one returns an incorrect value, `0xF193BA67BF66D733C10099B62D06F19AD98B1022`. QED. The T-SQL code is bogus.

Comment: I was aware of that. The question was whether I was using the HMAC sql function incorrectly (in the conversion of varchars, maybe?), or if the function is bogus as you suggest. Sorry if that wasn't clear.